# empty json value form editbox blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal

i'm new in unreal engine , i have a editbox to enter code and then it be persisted to a server via http request , using blueprints i made this graph , but always in server console it display that the code is empty when i click  to the button ( on pressed) , it mean that the data from  the editbox is not converted to json and it's empty , [image]

how can i solve it